# How to change the button position during landscape mode in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift3, autolayout

In this I need to change the position of delete button during landscape mode and that to it need to display beside the stepper can anyone help me how to implement this and here is the image for that and in the empty space I need to display the delete button

[image]

Comment: take `contraisnts` outlet you want to change then update it when the orientation is landscape mode

Comment: but how to give leading for stepper using constraints outlet ? @AnuragSharma

Comment: Just set the `trailing`

Comment: if u set trailing only then for different devices like iPhone 7 or iPhone 7plus the spacing will be increasing then what should I do at that time ?

Comment: So, You can do one thing just give Right, top and fix width and height. Is it ok?

Comment: This seems like a good case for size classes: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Size-ClassSpecificLayout.html

Comment: without trailing leading then it is not possible to display the button for example I was designing on iPhone 7 screen layout in story board then if u run the application on iPhone 5 definitely it will be missing @AnuragSharma

Comment: Can you please tell me where you want your stepper exactly? you can update your question with images :)

Comment: no stepper place is same in portrait or landscape but the delete button I need to place beside the stepper @AnuragSharma

Comment: delete button I need to place on empty space shown on right @AnuragSharma

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are already handling orientation and you receive events correctly I find it best if you create double constraints and manipulate their priority.

In storyboard place the button on one of the positions and add all constraints needed for it. Set all priorities to 900 (will explain later why not 1000) and confirm the layout is OK.

Now set these constraint priorities to 100 and start adding constraints for the other layouts. Set these constraints priorities to 900 and confirm the layout works for this scenario as well.

At this point you would need to change the priorities of one set to 900 and other to 100 to swap the mode. So now go into coding...

You will need outlets for these constraints which will be painful to drag all of them, name them and add then change the priority for each. But luckily you may use arrays for this so add the following in your code:

```
@IBOutlet var portraitConstraints: [NSLayoutConstraint]?
@IBOutlet var landscapeConstraints: [NSLayoutConstraint]?
```

Now simply drag all of the constraints into these 2 arrays as outlets.

The rest is pretty straight forward. Something like:

```
func setMode(mode: LayoutMode, animated: Bool) {
    switch mode {
    case .portrait:
        portraitConstraints?.forEach { $0.priority = 900 }
        landscapeConstraints?.forEach { $0.priority = 100 }
    case .landscape:
        portraitConstraints?.forEach { $0.priority = 100 }
        landscapeConstraints?.forEach { $0.priority = 900 }
    }
    UIView.animate(withDuration: animated ? 0.3 : 0.0) { 
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}
```

**About not setting a constraint priority to 1000:**

It is not allowed to change the priority of a constraint that has a priority set to 1000. Don't know why, don't care why.

**EDIT: This seems to be unclear so let me give you an example from your case:**

Assume you have a view that holds "Mobile", "1", "20.00KD", "-/+" called `inputContainer`, a delete button called `deleteButton` and image view on the left called `imageView`.

Now the portrait mode you would set the constraints as:

- `inputContainer.top = superView.top + t`
- `inputContainer.leading = imageView.trailing + a`
- `deleteButton.leading = inputContainer.leading`
- `deleteButton.top = inputContainer.bottom + b`
- `deleteButton.bottom = superView.bottom - t`

Then in landscape you would have:

- `inputContainer.center.y = superView.center.y`
- `inputContainer.leading = imageView.trailing + a`
- `deleteButton.center.y = switchView.center.y`
- `deleteButton.leading = inputContainer.trailing + b`

Now set one of these to priority of 900 and others to 100 in storyboard. Then connect all of these constraints into appropriate arrays in your code. That is it.

Comment: how to give constraints for other layout(i.e.. 100) that I didn't get you what u r  saying ? @Matic Oblak

Comment: Assume you would have 2 screens in storyboard. One has a layout defined for portrait mode and the other for landscape mode. Now this button would have some constraints in portrait where it is at bottom and some constraints in landscape to be shown on right. In your case you add all of these constraints; for portrait and landscape mode on the same element, the same button. But you set one set of constraint to have priority 100 and others to 900. Then those with higher priority will take effect which you then manipulate in code.

Comment: how to place 2 story boards with orientation change(i.e.. portrait and landscape) I don't know as I was new to swift 3 please explain clearly ?

Comment: @VamsiKrishnaSurathi You put only 1 storyboard. I said "assume", imagine you had 2... Anyway I updated the question to give you an example. See if this clears things out.

Comment: @Matic Nicely explained, But it will become a lot of code. Cannot we do it by simply taking two constraints outlet and managing the `constant` by just identifying the device and its orientation?

Comment: @AnuragSharma What do you mean about lots of code? In the code all you add are 6 lines; you need 2 array outlets and 2 forEach statements to control priority in the array for 2 states. Those points I added in example are meant in storyboard, not in the code.